# How to creating a custom table widget in dojo?

Tags: dojo

Recently I have started using Dojo for programming applications interfaces and am new to Dojo and my first assignment is to create a custom table widget with rows showing file list from the database and the file icon. The widget will be similar to a data grid but we want to use a table like for the listing because data-grid can be heavy to the network at times. Thank you your help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, lets say you instantiate your custom widget with a datastore, as does the grid. Your store, depending on which type (example: itemfilereadstore) has a listing of its items and the following will process them whilst creating rows into your widget

```
<script>
    dojo.declare("myTable", [dijit._Templated], {
     // define which template to instantiate on your domNode (in this case, table becomes the domNode of your widget)
     templateString: '<table><thead dojo-attach-point="headNode"></thead><tbody dojo-attach-point="bodyNode"></tbody></table>',

     constructor: function(args) {
       args = args || {};
       if(!args.store) console.warn("No store supplied");
       this.store = args.store
       // Note; there are a number of methods to achieve this hook,
       // depending on which type of datastore is in use
       this.store.fetch({ onComplete: dojo.hitch(this, "_onload") });
     },
     // function to be called whenever the store has fetched an item set
     _onload: function(items) {
       var _t = this, store = _t.store, head = _t.headNode, body = _t.bodyNode;
       var headIsFilled = false;
       // 'haxed' reset of current setup, simply resetting innerhtml
       _t.rowIdentifiers = [];
       _t.rows = [];
       head.innerHTML = "<tr></tr>";
       head = head.firstChild;
       body.innerHTML = "";
       dojo.forEach(items, function(item) {
           // generic way of simply showing all of contents available in store
           // prefereably, set this structure in an argument while constructing and
           // fill head with, say _t.layout
           if(!headIsFilled) {
              // loops the first item, making sure not to take in any internal references, should check for item
              for(var i in item) if(item.hasOwnProperty(i) && i != "_S" && i != "_RI") {
                 dojo.place("<th>"+i+"</th>");
                 _t.rowIdentifiers.push(i);
              }
              headIsFilled = true; // only once
           }
           var tr = dojo.create("tr", null, body);
           var row = { el : tr }
           var cell;
           dojo.forEach(_t.rowIdentifiers, function(key) {
             cell = dojo.create("td", {innerHTML : store.getValue(item, key)},  tr);
             row[key] = cell.innerHTML; // the toString value of item
           });
           _t.rows.push(row);
       });
     }
    });
</script>
```

Code has not been evaluated, but should give a general idea of how to startup a widget.

Note a couple things in the code; `templateString` is what the basic html layout should be and has a number of 'magic' conventions, in this example only attachpoints are used to have the _Templated mixin make references in the widget to its domNodes

See following as starter tutorials and for general reference:

http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/understanding_widget/

http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/templated/

Comment: thank you for the help but the data should be pass to the table rows via json data format and the first column of each row should be a check box and the second column i string and the third column an image icon of the file.

Comment: now, thats why there is a grid component with comperators and cell renderer / format functionality.. i dont get why wrapping json data into a store is a problem however, its easy enough to make your own `xhr.load(response) { for each item in eval(response) construct tr` function. Give a sample of what your JSON looks like and how you wish to show it with a html-snippet and answer will come